# Flask/Swagger - Swagger doesn't send correct parameters

Tags: python, flask, swagger

everyone. I have API: /api/movies/"movie_id" and it returns me is movie found or not. It works well, but when I in swagger in sends:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jan/2020 17:19:34] "GET /api/movies/%7Bmovie_id%7D HTTP/1.1" 4
04 -
```

Swagger doesn't send correct arguments to my GET function.

Update:

```
class IDMovies(Resource):
    @swagger.operation(
        notes='Get info about a movie by id',
        nickname="getmovie",
        responseClass=ResponseIDMoviesSuccess,
        parameters=[
            {
                "name": "movie_id",
                "description": "ID of a movie to return",
                "required": True,
                "allowMultiple": False,
                "paramType": "string",
                "dataType": "JSON"
            }],
        responseMessages=[
            {
                "message": "Successful operation",
                "code": 200
            },
            {
                "message": "Not found movie",
                "code": 404
            }
        ])
    def get(self, movie_id):
        movie = Movies.query.filter_by(imdbid=movie_id).first()
        if movie != None:
            movie = movie.__repr__()
            return {'movie': movie, 'status': 200, 'error': False}
        else:
            return {'error_msg': "Not found movie", 'status': 404, 'error': True}, 404

@swagger.model
@swagger.nested(movie=MovieItem.__name__)
class ResponseIDMoviesSuccess:
    def __init__(self, movie, status, error):
        pass

    resource_fields = {
            'movie': fields.Nested(MovieItem.resource_fields),
            'status': fields.Integer(attribute='status'),
            'error': fields.Boolean(attribute='error')
        }
```

**init**.py:

```
api.add_resource(routes.IDMovies, r'/api/movies/<string:movie_id>')
```

Comment: `%7B` and `%7C` are the URL encoding for `{` and `}` respectively. You will have to check where it comes from in your swagger instance. Probably a variable substitution gone wrong

Comment: Please post the source code and annotations for the `GET /api/movies/movie_id` operation.

Comment: If I correct understand you, there it is

Comment: I think it should be `"paramType": "path"` and `"dataType": "string"`. Can you try and see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter definition contains some incorrect values. You need to use `"paramType": "path"` and `"dataType": "string"`.